# String.IsNullOrEmpty in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, strings, null

I am aware of it being frowned upon to do something like write C# in JavaScript. (see [this](https://blog.codinghorror.com/you-can-write-fortran-in-any-language/) if you don't know what I'm talking about)

But as a judgement call, I think we could stand to have a relatively simple check for values that are `null` or empty, so I'm looking for feedback on this implementation of `String.isNullOrEmpty`.

```
String.isNullOrEmpty = function (value) {
    return (!value || value == undefined || value == "" || value.length == 0);
}
```

Comment: Aren't the first checks redundant after you've already tried to call `toString` on `value`?

Comment: Possibly.... I was thinking if I were to call a "static" String.isNullOrEmpty(). Not sure if I need it.

Comment: That revision is no good, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703102/typeof-undefined-vs-null) and other posts. You've radically changed the meaning of the function.

Comment: Not following you on that second comment. "You've radically changed the meaning of the function" I just removed that first try, catch. I didn't change any comparison operators. Maybe you should give me your thoughts in a full answer form.

Comment: Come to think of it. Because I am going to use it as such, would it be better if if(String.isNullOrEmpty(51354.toString())){} Or should the isNullOrEmpty handle casting

Comment: I'm not really an authoritative source on javascript, I was just trying to comment in general :) I'll try to write something up tomorrow unless someone more knowledgeable turns up. What I meant with my comment was that your two version returns different answers for something like `0` or `false` and undefined variables.

Comment: Would not a `return !value;` suffice?

Comment: @Terrance please take this C# away. `!string` is what you want, `String.isNullOrEmpty(string)` is an abomination

Comment: @Raynos Please elaborate. How do you mean? (How would !string check for empty strings for one and how is String.isNullOrEmpty() an abomination for two) As far as abstraction or performance or what?

Comment: @Terrance `!"" === true` and `!null == true` and `String.isNullOrEmpty` is just bloat that exists for no purpose other then "C# does it, it must be the best"

Comment: @Raynos If it makes you feel better I can certainly change the name of the method. I just needed something that insures that all checks  are made in dealing with string validation. And since we are a microsoft shop it seems to make the most sense to use something that would be considered a familiar construct. I could care less that it is a ".NET" thing. As long as the code base doesn't have if(val.length==0) sometimes and other times if(val!=undefined&&val!=null&&val!="") other times. We could call it isNil or isNothing if it insures its usage.

Comment: @Terrance I'm saying what's wrong with `if (!val) {` instead of `if(val === "" || val === null) {`

Comment: the link does not work anymore

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam the OG site apears to be dead but, I added a  different article discussing the issue. Hope that helps :P

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Starting with:

```
return (!value || value == undefined || value == "" || value.length == 0);
```

Looking at the last condition, if value == "", it's length MUST be 0. Therefore drop it:

```
return (!value || value == undefined || value == "");
```

But wait! In JS, an empty string is false. Therefore, drop `value == ""`:

```
return (!value || value == undefined);
```

And `!undefined` is true, so that check isn't needed. So we have:

```
return (!value);
```

And we don't need parentheses:

```
return !value
```

Q.E.D.

Comment: i must say... bravo

Comment: @ndp Gotta give it to you. That was complete and concise. Nice.

Comment: @ndp, Great answer! It's bit confusing for a moment tho... Please add a conclusion to your answer stating it's the final solution, for quick reference, thanks.

Comment: A really Great Answer ndp!
I added a screen shot in a reply that shows verfies it and shows execution for those who don't immediately get it.

 var A;
 var B = null;
 var C = "test";
 console.log("is A nullOrEmpty %o", !A);
 console.log("is B nullOrEmpty %o", !B);
 console.log("is C nullOrEmpty %o", !C);

Comment: But if someone passes it as a boolean value of false, then it might return the false positive. I think we need to add the check for that as-well.

Comment: What if the value is not a type of string, e.g. a number?

Comment: I've upvoted `return value == null || value === ""` described below as doing exactly what the function name says. Yes! But I think the larger (implicit) point may be that a function like this-- so convenient in Java-- is not necessary in Javascript.

Comment: Considering the method needs to validate a `string`, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/82633/133464 is more appropriate. `!value` tests the more general `falsey`.

Answer (score 17):

There are just a few revisions I would make.

First, *always* use `===` instead of `==` in Javascript. You can read more about that [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript).

Second, since [`undefined` is mutable](http://wtfjs.com/2010/02/15/undefined-is-mutable), I would reccomend using

```
typeof value === "undefined"
```

instead of

```
value === undefined
```

Third, I would remove the `!value` and `value === ""` conditions. They are redundant.

### My Revision

I would use a slightly different approach than you:

```
String.isNullOrEmpty = function(value) {
  return !(typeof value === "string" && value.length > 0);
}
```

This checks if the type of the value is `"string"` (and thus non-null and not undefined), and if it is not empty. If so, it is not null or empty.

Note that this returns `true` for non-string inputs, which might not be what you want if you wanted to throw an error for an unexpected input type.

Answer (score 9):

Your function unexpectedly returns `true` for the following non-string values:

- `false`
- `0`
- `Number.NaN`
- `[[]]`
- `[]`

It's quite possible that `!value` though it is similarly sloppy, would suffice, in which case you wouldn't need to define this function at all.  But if you create a function that is named `isNullOrEmpty`, then it should do just that.

```
function String.isNullOrEmpty(value) {
    return value == null || value === "";
}
```

Note that `value == null` is shorthand for `value === null || value === undefined`.

Comment: This is clean. Using coercion is not evil as many might suggest. As long as you realize you are doing it and how and WHY it works.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `Object.prototype.isNullOrEmpty = function() { alert(this) }`.  This ties it to the String object in all instances.  This would start to give you access to use strings and variables like `"".isNullOrEmpty` or `var x = null; x.isNullOrEmpty();`

If your intent is to use it as a function to pass in variables: `String.isNullOrEmpty();`

Comment: Except some people don't like extending the native prototypes.

Comment: Additionally, the example with `null` won't work.

Comment: And it doesn't work with `undefined` either.

Answer (score 3):

Ryan and seand are spot on: This achieves your end.

```
Object.prototype.isNullOrEmpty = function(value){
    return (!value);
}
```

This is what I love about *JavaScript*!

Comment: Just make sure nobody else implements a different isNullOrEmpty in Object.prototype and heavily relies on his implementation.  Patching Object.prototype is evil.

Comment: Doesn't work with null and undefined value

Comment: This is why I hate JavaScript!